# Playing Die2Nite from Germany

Tags: die2nite

As Die2Nite was released recently and quite some people seem to enjoy playing it I also wanted to try it out. But when I try to register I get the following message

```
Registration is not possible in your country.
```

I couldn't find any information about that on the website itself.

Is it possible to register from another country via proxy, VPN etc. and then play afterwards directly from Germany? Or does it check the country every time?

Would this be allowed according to their Terms of Service (I could not find them on the website)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die2Nite may not available from Germany still because there's [a German-only version of the game](http://www.dieverdammten.de/) (and [a France-only version of the game too](http://hordes.fr), for that matter) that has been around for longer and is more complete.

This'll change as the "worldwide" version of Die2Nite grows to feature-parity, possibly. Motion Twin has hinted, however, that each community may very well go their separate ways for the time being.

That said, proxy and VPN would work. I haven't checked their terms, however, as I can't find them.

Comment: Why can't they just add a link to the german or french version of the game? That would make things much clearer.

Comment: @Fabian They want to keep the communities separate and unaware of each other.

Comment: That's worked well, apparently. ;-)